# Поиск зависимостей в наборе числ на php

Tags: php, алгоритм

Здравствуйте! Нужно найти зависимость в наборе чисел, при генерации использовался генератор случайных чисел, какой именно не знаю. Сгенерировано от 0 до 15 включительно.
Вот набор чисел:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 14
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 8
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 14
    [6] => 0
    [7] => 11
    [8] => 5
    [9] => 1
    [10] => 4
    [11] => 13
    [12] => 12
    [13] => 8
    [14] => 7
    [15] => 6
    [16] => 4
    [17] => 0
    [18] => 12
    [19] => 11
    [20] => 12
    [21] => 1
    [22] => 6
    [23] => 8
    [24] => 12
    [25] => 1
    [26] => 15
    [27] => 12
    [28] => 9
    [29] => 7
    [30] => 0
    [31] => 8
    [32] => 3
    [33] => 12
    [34] => 12
    [35] => 15
    [36] => 14
    [37] => 15
    [38] => 12
    [39] => 2
    [40] => 6
    [41] => 11
    [42] => 2
    [43] => 5
    [44] => 3
    [45] => 9
    [46] => 4
)
```

К примеру, зная первые числа `14, 2, 5, 8`, нужно предугадать следующие числа. Что посоветуете для решения данной задачи? Решить пробую, используя php.

Comment: Может я тупой, но я зависимостей не вижу, а пхп уж тем более.

Comment: Есть методы для теста ГСЧ, возможно в этом направлении двигаться?

Comment: А неурезанная по модулю 16 последовательность есть? Хотя, даже с такой можно провести тесты на конкретные генераторы.

Comment: Буду очень благодарен, если поможете в этом вопросе с примерами на php)

Comment: @user265161 "пример" будет готовым алгоритмом. Да еще и непонятным для вас. Да еще и не на PHP, потому что производительность у PHP никакая. Начните решать задачу "в лоб", может вам и этого хватит.

Comment: С примерами я разберусь, мне главное на деле немного покажите и расскажите по подробнее о алгоритмах, какие лучшие использовать для теста. А насчёт неурезанной последовательности по модулю 16 пока не проверял, как лучше проверить? Через ГСЧ генерировать числа с диапазоном по больше и делить по модулю на 16? И после проверять, будут ли совпадения по заданным числам?

Comment: Вам тут нажны статистические методы, имхо. Линейная регрессия - построить модель на существующих данных и использовать её для предсказывания будущих значений.

Comment: Если использован мало-мальски нормальный генератор, то задача решения не имеет.

Comment: n.osennij можете привести пример для заданных чисел?

Comment: Остановился пока на тест DIEHARD и NIST, поясните, как провести эти тесты или где найти программу, которая проведёт такие тесты для набора моих чисел.